# Adding removed attributes back on hover method

Tags: javascript, jquery

have used the following code to remove the style and id attributes from my html, but I would like them to come back once the visitor moves to another element. I'm fairly new to jQuery and have no idea how to achieve that. I would really appreciate somebody's help.

```
<div class="base" style="background-image: url(img/3.jpg);">
  <div id="overlay"></div>
</div>

<script>
  $('.base').hover(function(){
    $(this).removeAttr('style').children().removeAttr('id');
  }, function(){
    $(this).addBack();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Why would you want to remove an id on hover? Are you trying to avoid applying some css?

Comment: I'm removing the id because it is set to display none. when I remove it the content of the div is revealed. I am hiding the elements until someone hovers over it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work :

```
<div class="base" style="background-image: url(img/3.jpg);">
  <div id="overlay"></div>
</div>

<script>
  $('.base').hover(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.data('style', $this.attr('style')).removeAttr('style').children().each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.data('id', $this.attr('id')).removeAttr('id');
    });
  }, function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.attr('style',$this.data('style')).removeData('style').children().each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.attr('id', $this.data('id')).removeData('id');
    });
  });

</script>
```

Basically we are storing attribute values in jQuery data arrays. I didn't test it but it should work, I've used this approach more than once..
Updated the code, and here is a working [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/VELd7/)

Comment: thanks that's amazing. it does almost exactly what I want it to do. it hides and brings back the background image. there is some issue with the id. it doesn't seem to be removed as the content of the div is not revealed as it was before.

Comment: hmm still the same. I have the entire project in a codepen http://codepen.io/mxquel/pen/KuFni

Comment: it's the old code this might make it easier to see what I want to achieve. I really appreciate your help btw.

Comment: This updated code must work, you have there a jsfiddle link where you can see it in action (it removes/restores ID on child nodes) .. here is the link again : http://jsfiddle.net/VELd7/ and here is your project forked with that function applied : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EDmJA

Comment: I've forked the code on codepen so you can see the old http://codepen.io/mxquel/pen/KuFni and new http://codepen.io/mxquel/pen/xevIr version. somehow there is an issue with the id handling because the content that is inside the div with the id is not displayed once the id is removed. I'm only marginally understanding what we are doing so I don't understand why it doesn't work

Comment: It's quite simple implementation, we are using internal data structure to temporary store the id/styles during the hover mouse, and after mouse-out we are restoring those values simply put..
Looking at those two examples they are both using your old code (look at the end of the html - there is a <script> tag containing old code. You have mine forked version that works ok here : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EDmJA

Comment: brilliant! it will probably take me the rest of the night to take this apart and understand it fully. worth a mention in the acknowledgement section :0) thanks soo much

Answer (score 2):

You have a wrong idea of what **[addBack()](http://api.jquery.com/addback/)** does, anyway the best here might be to use CSS classes.

Something like:

```
  $('.base').hover(function(){
    $(this).addClass('myClass');
  }, function(){
    $(this).removeClass('myClass');
  });
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/7nZLF/)

The part of the code where you remove the ID is irreversible, so I would find a alternative behaviour/solution there...

Comment: I think you are right and I don't really understand addBack. I need to use a style element to apply a background picture in this case. So while I could try and use adding and removing classes for the id css I would still face the issue with the style attribute